# how does i redirect to network

Tags: django, namespaces

I am trying to add user in one app and then calling network app to to display the user profile.

but i am not able to access my network app. what am i doing wrong here.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if request.POST['username'] and request.POST['password']:
                username = request.POST['username']
                password = request.POST['password']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        return HttpResponse(reverse("network"))
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("alpha")
        else:
            return LoginForm()
```

and my url file is

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^login', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^register', views.RegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration'),
url(r'network', include('network.urls', namespace="network", app_name='network')),
```

how do i access my network url becosause this is not working

Comment: Have you tried `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('network:network'))` ?

Comment: here i am just trying to print the reverse url to my network app just to check if its working

Comment: @nik_m its replying "'network' is not a registered namespace"

Comment: Try changing `url(r'network', include('network.urls', namespace="network", app_name='network'))` to `url(r'network', include('network.urls'))` and inside the `network.url` declare `app_name='network'`.

Comment: @nik_m still not working..

Comment: Can you add the content of network.urls file?

Comment: 'from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.http import request
from network import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.Account.as_view(), name='account'),
]
'